# Как лучше переходить на другие страницы php

Tags: php

Как лучше переходить на другие страницы php. Я так понимаю, что html надо открывать так

```
       include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/views/index.html';
```

а php вот так

```
       header("Location:  /home.php"); 
       exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`header("Location:  /home.php");` - совершит переход.

А первый вариант всего лишь откроет нужный файл (index.html), но перехода не будет.